# "... respectively are ..." vs "... are respectively ..."

Tags: adverbs, syntactic-analysis, adverb-position

I would use *respectively* in either one of the following ways:

> "Figures 1 to 3 are respectively front, top and bottom views of the object",
>
> "Figures 1 to 3 are front, top and bottom views of the object respectively"

(with a strong preference for the former).

But I am presented it as:

> "Figures 1 to 3 respectively are front, top and bottom views of the object".

Is the later form a more formal (such as when used in official documents, patents, literature) use of *respectively* or is it incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

Using *respectively* at the end of the sentence is the normal structure:
"Figures 1 to 3 are front, top and bottom views of the object, respectively."

However, *respectively* **can** be placed **parenthetically** in the middle of the sentence as in the other two forms. All are acceptable. Note, however, that a parenthetical needs to be separated by commas on both sides:
"Figures 1 to 3 are, respectively, front, top and bottom views of the object."
"Figures 1 to 3, respectively, are front, top and bottom views of the object."

Comment: To add to this, some internal style guides require "Figures 1, 2 and 3" to make the list explicit and to emphasize the one-to-one pairing imparted by "respectively."

Comment: @Kris: are both commas mandatory on both sides of the parenthetical? It seems to me that the commas would add some unnecessary heaviness (or slowness upon reading due to an over-emphasis on "respectively") to what is otherwise a short and straightforward sentence. I would see them as optional.

Comment: @Chemomechanics given the enumerative nature of respectively, I'd agree with you internal style guides.

Comment: OP, yes, a parenthetical should necessarily be separated by commas. Sometimes a dash may be used instead. The reason is that a parenthetical expression interrupts the sentence structure - try reading the sentence without the expression: it is still grammatical, makes sense and is complete on its own. HTH.

Comment: @Kris: is *respectively*, as used in the 1st and 3rd form in my question, a parenthetical? Does the fact that it "can be placed parenthetically" (as you wrote in your answer) make it necessarily parenthetical? I would tend to think that  that "respectively" in the forms 1 and 3 may or may not be considered  parenthetical. Well, I think that could be the subject of questions about parenthetical ... A side note: it seems "parenthetical" is an adjective, not a noun.

Comment: Yes, it is, in *all* those cases. When it appears at the end, it's only preceded by a comma and the sentence terminates with a period. "My colleagues, Ann and Joe, work in advertising and sales, respectively."  However, it is common to omit these delimiting commas these days. "In terms of population, California and New York rank first and second respectively."  *Parenthetical* is both an adjective and a noun ( https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parenthetical ). In fact, most times nouns can be used adjectivally as well. (Examples are from the web.)